# Keep property of another UserControl

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, user-controls

I have the following code:

```
public partial class FenetreMenu : UserControl 
{
    private int nbJoueurs { get; set; }
    private int typeJeu; { get; set; }
    private List<CJoueur> ListJoueurs { get; set; }
```

and

```
public partial class FenetreJeu01 : UserControl 
{ 
    private int nbPlayer { get; set; }
    private int typeGame { get; set; }
    private List<CJoueur> ListJoueurs { get; set; }
```

These are two `UserControl`s and I want to send the 3 properties of the first `UserControl` to the second.

And when I want to add FenetreJeu01 in FenetreMenu I have an error with my FenetreJeu01, it's write "Partial declarations of 'type' must not specify different base classes."

Thank you in advance. Valentin

Comment: if you use DependencyProperties instead of common properties, you will be able to bind properties of first control instance to properties of second control instance

Comment: Yes it's a good idea but how can I do it ? :) @ASh